Use the same logging.Handler in different main files
Cheers!
I am developping a Django Projekt and I want to display my backend loggings to the forntend. Thats why i created a central logging Handler that pushes logs into a buffer. Every 20 sec my frontend sends a request to flush the buffer and display the log events.
Central Loging Class (log.py):
import logging

class BufferedLogHandler(logging.Handler):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.log_buffer = []  # Lokaler Puffer für Logs

    def emit(self, record):
        log_entry = self.format(record)  # Format den Log-Eintrag
        self.log_buffer.append(log_entry)
    
    def create_external_log(self, level=None, timestamp=None, message=None):
        asctime = timestamp
        msg = message
        record = logging.LogRecord(
                        level=level,   
                        msg=msg, 
                        asctime=asctime,
                        lineno=0,
                        exc_info=None,
                        args=None,
                        name= None,
                        pathname="frontend",
                    )
        self.emit(record=record)
        return BufferedLogHandler.create_empty_response()

    def flush_buffer(self):
        logs_to_send = self.log_buffer[:]
        print(f'logs_to_send:{logs_to_send}')
        print("---------------------")
        self.log_buffer = []
        return logs_to_send
    
    @staticmethod
    def create_empty_response():
        response = {'message':""}
        return response
    
buffered_handler = BufferedLogHandler()


def setup_logger(bufferedHandler):
    # Den Logger holen (Root-Logger oder benannten Logger)
    logger = logging.getLogger()  # Du kannst auch den Root-Logger verwenden

    # Setze das Log-Level (z.B. DEBUG, INFO)
    logger.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)

    # Erstelle einen Handler (z.B. für Konsole oder Datei)
    file_handler = logging.FileHandler('myapp.log')  # Für eine Log-Datei

    # Erstelle ein Format für die Log-Nachrichten
    formatter = logging.Formatter('%(asctime)s - %(levelname)s - %(filename)s - %(lineno)d - %(message)s')

    # Setze das Format für beide Handler
    bufferedHandler.setFormatter(formatter)
    file_handler.setFormatter(formatter)

    # Füge beide Handler dem Logger hinzu
    logger.addHandler(buffered_handler)
    logger.addHandler(file_handler)

    return logger

My first main class is the manage.py:
from mypath import log
logger = log.setup_logger(log.buffered_handler)
...
logger.info("Logs have been sent to the frontend.")

My second main class is the generate_pictures.py (management/commands/generate_picutres.py)
from another_relative_path import log
logger = log.setup_logger(log.buffered_handler)
...
logger.info("Picture has been created!")

I cannot seem to get both main files to interact with the same buffer in the logging.handler object. When checking the IDs of each imported object log.buffered_handler they dont match.
What have I missed? How can i access the same buffer from both files?

from another_relative_path import log - what's that? Why isn't it just from mypath import log again? Do you have some tricky way you are doing imports? If there are two different paths to this .py file, python may be importing it twice.

Are these all in the same process? Can you print out something like print(os.getpid(), id(log)) to see if we have 1 process and are getting the same log module in all places?

For manage.py I got 7067 123373899111296.
For generate_pictures.py I got 7467 123884374843776.
... still struggling with the basics. Somehow I thought one could just share the object between different processes.
Any recommendations on how to work around my problem? Should the generator process send its data to manage.py via an API or would you recommend multiprocessing?

You have multiple processes - as evidenced by the different PIDs - and its difficult to get processes to view each other's memory. Especially when they may be running at different times. But all you want is some pretty basic logging and there are  many solutions to choose from. Here's is django's logging page, its likely all you need. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.1/topics/logging/

If you want to have a share logger in all your modules, you should create it in a single place.
I would make that place your log.py file. At the end of it, create the logger:
logger = setup_logger(buffered_handler)

and then in your other modules import it with
from mypath.log import logger

which you can use directly.

Thanks, but that still doesnt work. The IDs of all three objects (in log.py, main1 and main2) dont match. Any other idea?

I just did a test of just this, with file1.py having from log import logger, and file2.py having the same, then in main.py I did from file1 import logger as l1 and from file2 import logger as l2, and there print(l1 is l2) prints True. Can you confirm exactly how you applied my solution? If all your files are in the same process, the logger everywhere should be the same object.

And, now I have a doubt: you said "My first main class is the manage", and "My second main class...". Do you mean "main class" as in these classes are the main of two separate processes? If so, no, they can't possibly share the same logger object.
